# Rails Admin generating the wrong SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, rails-admin, acts-as-commentable

So I have a `Service` model that has many `Comment` using the `acts_as_commentable_with_threading` gem.

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Boilerplate gem generated code
end
```

Here's the schema the gem generates:

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "commentable_id",          default: 0
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.integer  "user_id",                 default: 0,   null: false
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "lft"
    t.integer  "rgt"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",         default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",       default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_score",   default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_total",   default: 0
    t.float    "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
  end
```

Rails admin is generating the wrong query when I try to access a Service. It sees the `has_many :comments` and jumps to it.

`http://localhost:5000/admin/service/999`

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column comments.service_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."servi...

---

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I believe it would be `has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy` because you need to tell ActiveRecord what the name of the appropriate column is. It is assuming it should be `service_id` unless you tell it differently.

Comment: Thanks a bunch that fixed the error when the page was loading. However, there is no link to "Comments" on the Rails Admin show page. Is there something else I need to do to be able to click like: "Show comments for this service"?

Comment: You haven't shown any of the code in your view.